# Rails: Using helper across all controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to access my **section_grades.rb** helper from anywhere in the application.

Currently in one section of my app, the finances section, I have this code in **finance_controller.rb**:

```
    include SectionGrades

    ...

    if current_user
      rainy_day_checker
      retirement_grade
      credit_card_grade
      spending_grade
    end
```

Do I move this into **application_controller.rb**? If so, what's the method I put it under? I tried and it said current_user is not defined.

Comment: You just put `include SectionGrades` right under `class ApplicationController`

Comment: In section_grades.rb though I have different methods. module SectionGrades
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def spending_grade. How do I call these methods?

Comment: You need to supply a bit more context, so I can understand better what you are trying to achieve. What kind of code do you have in `section_grades`? Why do you want to access it in the controller? Where in the `finance_controller` does that code live? What kinds of side effects do `rainy_day_checker` and `spending_grade` have?